# Why is a dynamically by C++ generated QML Item not aware of other pre-existing Items?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I have a `QQuickView` that displays a QML file which itself consists of several QML Items (in separate files). I'd like to add Items dynamically using C++ code. The dynamically added item should resize with the parent one, i.e. `width` and `height` properties reference parent.

For example, my target Item in QML looks like this:

```
// TargetContainer.qml

Grid {
    id: fillMeWithItemsContainer
    objectName: "fillMeWithItemsContainer"
}
```

The Item I want to add dynamically (maybe multiple times) looks like this:

```
// DynamicItem.qml

Rectangle {
    color: "white"

    height: fillMeWithItemsContainer.height
    width: height * 4/3
}
```

**Note that the rectangle references the container it is intended to reside in regarding height.**

`quickView` is populated with `TargetContainer`:

```
QQuickView *quickView = new QQuickView();
quickView->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/foo/bar/TargetContainer.qml"));
```

So I load a component

```
QQmlComponent dynamicallyLoadedComponent(
                quickView->engine(),
                QUrl("qrc:/foo/bar/DynamicItem.qml")
                );
```

And I create an Object out of it.

```
QObject *dynamicallyLoadedObject = dynamicallyLoadedComponent.create();
```

**Here I get an error** (in application output view):

```
DynamicItem.qml:4: ReferenceError: fillMeWithItemsContainer is not defined
```

`quickView` should be aware of the existence of `fillMeWithItemsContainer`, because it has been created before. However, `fillMeWithItemsContainer` is not a parent of `dynamicallyLoadedObject` (yet) and this could be the problem.

So I find the target Item by

```
QQuickItem *targetItem = quickView->rootObject()->findChild<QQuickItem*>("fillMeWithItemsContainer");
```

And reparent the previously created object

```
dynamicallyLoadedObject->setProperty("parent", QVariant::fromValue<QObject*>(targetItem ));
```

Note: I tried `dynamicallyLoadedObject->setParent()` before, but this seems to be a different kind of parent (`QObject` vs. parent property).

However, the width and height properties of `dynamicallyLoadedObject` are set to 0 (because of the reference error, I assume) and won't change. Even if I set them again programatically

```
dynamicallyLoadedObject->setProperty("height", "fillMeWithItemsContainer.height;");
dynamicallyLoadedObject->setProperty("width", "height * 4/3");
```

nothing changes.

**If I define DynamicItem directly in QML it works:**

```
Grid {
    id: fillMeWithItemsContainer
    objectName: "fillMeWithItemsContainer"

    DynamicItem {}
}
```

How do I make sure that dynamically added items can access Items that have been in the QML view before? Alternatively: What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dynamicallyLoadedObject->setProperty("height", "fillMeWithItemsContainer.height;");
dynamicallyLoadedObject->setProperty("width", "height * 4/3");
```

This will not actually set a JavaScript binding on the properties. Instead, it will try to assign e.g. the string `"fillMeWithItemsContainer.height;"` to the property, which will fail since the property is of type `int`, not of type `QString`.
Assigning bindings to properties is actually not possible from within C++ (with some exceptions like `QQmlBinding`).

```
dynamicallyLoadedObject->setProperty("parent", QVariant::fromValue<QObject*>(targetItem ));
```

As Sergei mentioned, you need to call `QQuickItem::setParentItem` instead of setting the `parent` property. That is also a bit more typesafe than the general string-based `setProperty` API. Without a parent item, a QQuickItem will not be visible.
Reparenting will only change the parent item, which will affect layouting and a few other things. It will **not** change the *context* of the object. A context defines which objects/IDs are in the scope. The context can not be changed after an item has been created. Even if changing the parent would change the context, it is too late - the object has been created, and IDs/object are only looked up in the creation phase.

The solution is to pass the correct context to `QQmlComponent::create()`, which actually has an optional argument. You need to create your item in the context of `fillMeWithItemsContainer`, so you need to get a pointer to it (you did that already with `findChild`) and then retrieve its context, which is possible with `QQmlEngine::contextForObject()`. That should give you enough to figure out how to make it work.

I agree with Sergei though, you should prefer to dynamically create objects in JavaScript instead. Changing QML from within C++ is a layering violation, you should never access QML from C++, only the other way around, to have a nicer separation between UI and program logic.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, QML engine treats `DynamicItem` instance as a non-graphical item since it is casted to `QObject*`. Thus it is not rendered. It has to be at least `QQuickItem*` to be rendered.

I believe you experience same problem with `setParent()` since `parent` property refers to parent `QQuickItem` and might no be the same as `QObject` parent.

Two questions:

1. Why wouldn't you create dynamic objects in JS?
2. Is it possible to use relative `parent` instead of absolute `fillMeWithItemsContainer`?

p.s. I assume you understand this is rather irregular way of using QML and have strong reasons for such hacky approach.

Comment: The casting here is irrelevant - QQmlComponent::create() creates an object of correct type, which in this case is (a subclass of) QQuickItem. Casting that pointer will not change its type in any way, it will stay a QQuickItem.

Comment: @tmcguire Thanks for correction. For this case casting of DynamicObject instance pointer to QObject is irrelevant. (I messed up with context properties.)